# Why can't I use the variable I created to specify the workbook and the sheet of a range"?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I created an auxiliary variable to make it easier for me when I refer to a worksheet from a workbook. But it doesn't work.

This generates the "error 91".

The line of "LastRow1..." becomes highlighted and if I delete this line of the code the line "If wb1.Cells(6, 10).Value ..." becomes highlighted.

I think it's because of the "wb1".

```
Sub test()
  Dim wb1 As Worksheet
  Dim LastRow1 As Long
  Dim lag_lead As String

  Set wb1 = Workbooks("name.xlsm").Sheets("sheet1")

    LastRow1 = wb1.Range("D6").End(xlDown).row
    If wb1.Cells(11, 7).Value = -4 Then lag_lead = "4"
    Else: lag_lead = "5"
    End If
End sub
```

Comment: In this line `LastRow1 = wb1.Range("D6").End(xlDown).row` is "row" actually lower case?

Comment: you're not even using the variable in your code... why is it there?

Answer (score 0):

replace `sht` with your `wb1` and replace and letter/col with what you want

```
'Using Find Function
  LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Using SpecialCells Function
  LastRow = sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'Ctrl + Shift + End
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Using UsedRange
  sht.UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
  LastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

'Using Table Range
  LastRow = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Rows.Count

'Using Named Range
  LastRow = sht.Range("MyNamedRange").Rows.Count

'Ctrl + Shift + Down (Range should be first cell in data set)
  LastRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
```